# How do I prevent MaxLength beeping or prevent application beeping altogether?

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, maxlength, beep

## My problem:

When my text box's `MaxLength` is reached, a beep sound is produced. I want to prevent this beeping and would even go so far as preventing all instances of beeping for my application if achievable.

I'm already familiar with how to mimic `MaxLength` using `Substring` and resetting the caret but in this particular instance, substituting `MaxLength` is not an option.

## To reproduce:

1. In Visual Studio, in design mode, drag a text box onto a fresh form.
2. Use the following as is:

**Code:**

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        TextBox1.MaxLength = 5
    End Sub
    Private Sub TextBox1_keypress(keyascii As Integer)
        If len(TextBox1.text) = 5 Then
            keyascii = 0
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

The above is an adaptation of examples I've come across online but has no effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test this:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyPress
    If Not e.KeyChar.Equals(ControlChars.Back) Then
        If Me.TextBox1.TextLength = Me.TextBox1.MaxLength Then
            e.Handled = True
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Tested. I can confirm that it works on my end. Much thanks. I was struggling to find a working solution online.