# How to disable beep sound for TextBox while trying to enter more characters than allowed

Tags: c#, winforms

I set `MaxLength` for my `TextBox` as `4`. When I try to enter 5th character, some Windows system beep sound appears. How to disable it?

Comment: You can try setting the max to 5 but program it stop responding to keypresses at 4.

Comment: Can you just tell us if it VB.Net or C#?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I prevent MaxLength beeping or prevent application beeping altogether?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26581697/how-do-i-prevent-maxlength-beeping-or-prevent-application-beeping-altogether)

Comment: @JimHewitt that question is for visuab basic by the way, but is similar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the discussion with Sievajet, try this other solution:

```
textBox1.KeyDown += (sender, e) => {
    TextBox tBox = sender as TextBox;
    if (tBox.Text.Length == tBox.MaxLength)
        e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
};
```

Note:
If you find that both solutions works, please choose Sievajet's answer as the good one, I'm more interested in the result, so maybe write me a comment.

Comment: Thank you both @Jimi and @Sievajet, I've used only `e.SuppressKeyPress = true;` and it was fine for me!

Answer (score 1):

You can simply fix this with the `KeyUp` event handler:

```
textBox1.KeyUp += ( sender , e ) => e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
```

This will prevent windows to get the max-length signal from the textbox.

Comment: Probably `e.SuppressKeyPress = true;`

Comment: You're right. e.Handled doesn't take care of pending WM_CHAR messages already built up in the message queue - so setting Handled = true does not prevent a KeyPress from occurring.

Comment: It is sent anyway in the KeyDown event. You should change .KeyUp with .KeyDown to suppress it for good.

Comment: It's not a problem if the keydown event is triggered. This is a one liner in the keyup event and will prevent more characters in the textbox. You'll need to do more checks in the keydown event.

Comment: It's missing the check if(TextBox1.Text.Lenght ==4). Just extend the Lambda { }

Comment: This is interesting. Are you sure your asterisk sound is enabled :)? Two different behaviors in such a common scenario is uncommon.